# Apache Virtual Hosts Override httpd.conf

Tags: configuration, virtualhost, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I'm confused as to how vhosts in Apache 2.4 work. I have enabled virtual hosts, and I have two websites set up on my server. I think that this means the default host (/var/www/html) doesn't work anymore. But which parts of httpd.conf are overrided by virtual hosts? Do the includes such as "conf.d" that are in httpd.conf apply to the virtual hosts or do I have to manually assign those? I have in httpd.conf a line which assigns a special header to RemoteIPHeader, do I have to include this line in each of my virtual host .conf files? Please help me understand how httpd.conf works when virtual hosts are enabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[Every Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/quickreference.html) lists the *context* in which it is valid. In other words where it is allowed to be used.

The [*context*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) can be any combination of:

> **s** - **server config** This means that the directive may be used in the server
>   configuration files (e.g., `httpd.conf`), but not within any
>   `<VirtualHost>` or `<Directory>` containers. It is not allowed in
>   `.htaccess` files at all.
>   **v** - **virtual host** This context means that the
>   directive may appear inside `<VirtualHost>` containers in the server
>   configuration files.
>   **d - directory** A directive marked as being valid in
>   this context may be used inside `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>`,
>   `<If>`, and `<Proxy>` containers in the server configuration files,
>   subject to the restrictions outlined in Configuration Sections.
>   **h - .htaccess** If a directive is valid in this context, it means that it
>   can appear inside per-directory `.htaccess` files. It may not be
>   processed, though depending upon the overrides currently active.

If a directive is used multiple times, both the context, the scope and the order the Directives are encountered determines [which directive will have precedence](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging).

With regards to [`VirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) entries the directives used there will override the default settings, but will only apply for that virtual host entry.

With name based virtual hosting the [first `<VirtualHost addr:port>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html#alg) becomes the default which will serve all requests that don't match any explicitly defined ServerName/ServerAlias names used in the other VirtualHost entries.